# What TV show/movie had a planet-eating web?

Tags: story-identification

Unfortunately, that's about all I can remember. I'm pretty sure it was a show, though it could have been a movie.

All I remember is that it was a sci-fi show in the aesthetic of Babylon 5, and the bad-guys at some point had a giant web that they would deploy around a planet, and there was some kind of climax when the weapon reached Earth.

For a long time I thought it WAS Babylon 5... until I watched B5.

EDIT: I've seen Lexx, Farscape, and TOS, but it wasn't any of those. It might have been the Death Cloud from Babylon 5: Call to Arms. I didn't know about that part of the B5 franchise (I've only seen the series). I'll have to go find out ;-)

Comment: http://lexx.wikia.com/wiki/Foreshadow

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tholian_web

Comment: http://www.farscapeworld.com/episodes/synopsis/10113.php or http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GiantSpider

Comment: My first thought was lexx as well. From the link Richard posted: *The Foreshadow's web-like armatures are a single massive primary weapon, that fires sheets of energy in the form of a massive Black Pack discharge*.

Comment: Actually... That sounds quite like one of the Babylon 5 spin-off movies - A Call To Arms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5:_A_Call_to_Arms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @andrewsi said, it is Babylon 5: A Call to Arms.

The "giant web" thing is known as a [Shadow Planet Killer](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Cloud) or a Death Cloud.

You can see it in the video below:

Comment: The description does sound like this, and it was my first guess. If the questioner is simply mistaken about it not being from *B5*, this would be it. That *Farscape* example also seems promising.

Comment: It would definitely explain how it had the aesthetic of B5, too :)